# C# Hotkey Box (AHK Hotkey Style)

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, autohotkey, key-bindings

I am trying within C# to create a similar Hotkey function as in AHK. Just like in any video game, you click in a box, press your hotkey and get it registered.
That's what I am trying to do with the textBox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Keybinder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "HELLO";
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char key = e.KeyChar;
            string keystring = Char.ToString(key);
            textBox1.Text = keystring;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, that I need to turn off the basic functions of the textBox, but I don't know how. For example: the cursor is still active and I can highlight the text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the property of the text box, Enabled to false, and then put the background color white and the font black, so it doesn´t seems like it was disabled, but you can not focus nor click on ir.

```
textBox1.Enabled = false;
```

By the way, I have a really simple library, that may be usefull.

https://github.com/PabloHorno/HotKeyDialog

Once you have the library referenced you can use it like this
or in a more simple way

```
var hotKey = new HotKey();

hotKey = HotKeyMessageBox.Show("Title", "A little description");

hotKey.ToString();
```

Or you can check if the user closes the box

```
 HotKey hotkey = new HotKey();

 if (HotKeyMessageBox.Show("Title", "Please press the key combination", out hotkey) == DialogResult.OK)
     label.Text = "You have pressed the keys: " + hotkey.ToString();
 else
     label.Text = "You have closed the dialog. There is no input";
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a TextBox, if you do not need its functionality?

Instead of turning off it's functions, you can create a simple custom control and put it on your form. Something like:

```
public class KeyInput : UserControl
{
    public string KeyString { get; set; } = "HELLO";

    public KeyInput() : base()
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        KeyString = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(KeyString, Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't there any way to implement a UserControl dynamically and not with an extra class?

Comment: @dewey, Actually, you can directly place a UserControl instance on the form and subscribe to its KeyPress and Paint events, if you want. However, as I think, this is not a very good way.